# color == null || decoration == null "Cannot provide both a color and a decoration"

Tags: flutter, dart

When we try to apply Container widget in the center of the screen at that time above error will generates.

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building Practice(dirty):
Assertion failed: file:///C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/container.dart:269:15
color == null || decoration == null
"Cannot provide both a color and a decoration\nTo provide both, use \"decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color)\"."

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Practice 

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 297:3  throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 38:3   assertFailed
```

When generating this error, i tried to fix this problem in various ways. This error is due to applying color property outside the BoxDecoration().

Comment: The error message literally says what's wrong and how to solve it

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

By applying color property inside the BoxDecoration, we can fix the above given problem as shown below :

```
body: Center(
  child: Container(
    width: 300.0,
    height: 300.0,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.grey,),     ),),
```